# How to ensure that a DataFrame has the correct index when converting to a geodataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I am attempting to create a geodataframe with newly calculated values that came from another dataframe. The new value list is longer than the dataframe from which they were calculated.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(_x, _y)]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)
gdf.plot(ax=df_usa.plot(figsize=(10,6)), marker='o', color='black', markersize=2)
```

The error

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

is thrown when the gdf line is executed.

How can I add this new list of values to the data frame so that they can be plotted onto the geodataframe map?

I am using geopandas and shapely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: reindex the smaller dataframe to have the same index as the larger one with NaNs for missing points.

Comment: Since the new values are in a list not a dataframe, is it possible to reindex with the list?